# Parser Error: Unexpected token ')' at column 36 in [display=!display;arr.push(new Date())] in ng:///AppComponent/template.html@14:47 ("

Tags: angular

My code:

```
    <div class='col-xs-12'>
        <button class='btn btn-primary' (click)="display=!display;arr.push(new Date())">Display Details</button>
        <p *ngIf="display;else elseblock">Secret Password=tune</p>
        <ng-template #elseblock><p>else block data</p></ng-template>
        <div *ngFor="let ar of arr">{{ar}}</div>
    </div>
```

I am getting the following error near arr.push

```
Parser Error: Unexpected token ')' at column 36 in [display=!display;arr.push(new 
  Date())] in ng:///AppComponent/template.html@14:47 ("     <ng-template 
  #elseblock><p>else block data</p></ng-template>
  <div *ngFor="let ar of arr">[ERROR ->]{{ar}}</div>
</div>
```

"): ng:///AppComponent/template.html@17:34

Comment: Thats probably because the html is not able top recognize the new operator and the Date(). Wrap it in a method in your component and use the method on the click

Answer (score 0):

Adding the code inside the `(click)` event, i.e. `"display=!display;arr.push(new Date())"` into its own function in the corresponding `*.component.ts` file makes it work.

[Stackblitz eg.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ivw8yd)

#### app.component.html

```
<div class='col-xs-12'>
    <button class='btn btn-primary' (click)="onButtonClick()">Display Details</button>
    <p *ngIf="display;else elseblock">Secret Password=tune</p>
    <ng-template #elseblock><p>else block data</p></ng-template>
    <div *ngFor="let ar of arr">{{ar}}</div>
</div>
```

#### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  display: boolean;
  arr: Date[] = [];

  onButtonClick() {
   this.display=!this.display;
   this.arr.push(new Date());
  }
}
```

In general, complex code in a template statement should be moved into its own function in the corresponding `*.component.ts` file, since a lot of Javascript such as `new` operators are not supported in template statements ([source](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-statements)).